# Using the open function. How can I specify the path?

Tags: python, function, file-io, path

I'm trying to open a file I created and I don´t get it. I suspect that the open function is not using the proper path... How can I put the path?

```
>>> filehandler = open(fruits.obj,'w')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'fruits' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `open` function takes a string containing the path to your file as its first argument. In your case, you didn't use a string, but you told Python to use the `obj` property of the `fruits` object. As there is no `fruits` object, you get a `NameError` exception.

You should probably change your program to :

```
>>> filehandler = open("fruits.obj", "w")
```

Comment: Its opened with write-only mode, you won't get an IOError if the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes:

```
>>> filehandler = open("fruits.obj",'w')
```

Comment: No matter - double quotes or single ones ;)